# Layout Is Different In Other Browsers

Tags: css

I want to make each browser page the same for my site but it is different in chrome than safari. Anyone wanna help me?

```css
body{
 background-image: url("http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Forest-Wallpaper-HD-12.jpg");
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 background-size: 1500px 1000px;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

.header{
 background-color: #000000;
 opacity: 0.8;
 height: 2500px;
 width: 1000px;
 background-position: center center; 
}

.header h1{
 color: red;
 size: 50px;
}

.top-banner{
 background-color: #D1D1D1;
 opacity: 0.8;
 height: 75px;
 top: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 
}

.top-banner a {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-family: Gang Of Three, alba, serif;
 color: rgba(134,130,255,1);
 
}

.top-banner a:hover {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 opacity: 0.7; 
}

.top-banner img {
position: relative;
top: 15px;
 
}


}

.lol {
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: normal;
 word-spacing: 250px;
}

.top-banner li {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: normal;
 word-spacing: 250px;
}

.header p {
 color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Nexus Arts</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
  <style>
a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 0.7; 
}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="top-banner">
 <ul class="lol">
  <li><font color="Black" size="5px"><a href="index.html">Home</a>             <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>       <img src="assets/imgs/nexus.jpg" width="58px" height="42px">     <a href="Staff.html">Staff</a>   <a href="Help.html">Help</a></font></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <center><div class="header">
 <center><h1>Hello Everyone</h1></center>
 <center><h1>This Website is still in BETA</h1></center>
 <center><p>Welcome to anybody that went on this website</p></center>
 <center><p>Our initial release is March 13th 2017</p></center
 </div></center
 </body>
</html>
```

Chrome: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6ehH.jpg)
Safari: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCOWi.jpg)

If you guys have any suggestions I NEED THEM or just edit my code :)

Comment: I feel like these two images are from different times

Comment: This question is very broad, going forward I would try to be a bit more precise about what you are looking for, or what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you putting all your navigation links in the same `<li>`? This causes the different behavior, each browser treats the white-space differently.

Put each entry in its own `<li>` and use CSS to place them properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter problems coding, it saves a headache to first check that you have a closed bracket for each opening and for html, a closing tag for each opening tag (if it requires one.)

Below we can see that two closing center tags are missing their ">":

```
<center><p>Welcome to anybody that went on this website</p></center>
<center><p>Our initial release is March 13th 2017</p></center
</div></center
</body>
```

> Most browsers will appear to stop reading any code that follows

We see the converse thing in the .css file wherein there is an extra "}":

```
.top-banner img {
position: relative;
top: 15px;

}


}
```

> Likewise, any style information below that bracket may be lost *depending on the browser.*